# Will DVD+RW work on my laptop drive marked RW?

Tags: dvd, burning

I purchase today moserbaer DVD that is: DVD+RW. Now I want to know whether my drive supports this DVD (i.e. the DVD can be burned)!

On my drive its written RW & ReWritable.

Also please see the below command output if it may help.

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$ sudo lshw | grep DVD
[sudo] password for ravbholua: 
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: DVD-RW DVRKD08RS
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$
```

> EDIT

I tried burning the DVD with my Ubuntu 13.10 iso but failed. Then I tried burning only 1 video file on the same DVD but that also got failed. I give the details below:

I tried burning Ubuntu 13.10 iso as below:

1st I tried via command line but failed:

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~/Documents/Other/special$ ls
ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~/Documents/Other/special$ sudo wodim -eject gracetime=30 ./ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso
wodim: No write mode specified.
wodim: Assuming -tao mode.
wodim: Future versions of wodim may have different drive dependent defaults.
Device was not specified. Trying to find an appropriate drive...
Looking for a DVD-R drive to store 895.00 MiB...
Detected DVD-R drive: /dev/dvdrw
Using /dev/cdrom of unknown capabilities
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 5
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'PIONEER '
Identification : 'DVD-RW DVRKD08RS'
Revision       : '1.02'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.
Using generic SCSI-3/mmc DVD-R(W) driver (mmc_mdvd).
Driver flags   : SWABAUDIO BURNFREE 
Supported modes: PACKET SAO
Speed set to 5540 KB/s
Starting to write CD/DVD at speed   4.0 in real unknown mode for single session.
Last chance to quit, starting real write in    0 seconds. Operation starts.
Errno: 5 (Input/output error), send opc scsi sendcmd: no error
CDB:  54 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
status: 0x2 (CHECK CONDITION)
Sense Bytes: 72 0B 00 00 00 00 00 0E 09 0C 00 00 00 02 00 08
Sense Key: 0x0 No Additional Sense, Segment 11
Sense Code: 0x00 Qual 0x02 (end-of-partition/medium detected) Fru 0x0
Sense flags: Blk 0 (not valid) 
cmd finished after 79.878s timeout 60s
wodim: OPC failed.
```

Then I used Brasero (GUI) for that but that also couldn't burn the Ubuntu iso. The error log is below:

```
Checking session consistency (brasero_burn_check_session_consistency brasero-burn.c:1739)
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroBurnURI stopping
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroBurnURI output set (IMAGE) image = /tmp/brasero_tmp_EM0F9W.bin toc = none
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroBurnURI no burn:// URI found
BraseroBurnURI stopping
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroLocalTrack stopping
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLocalTrack output set (IMAGE) image = /tmp/brasero_tmp_EUZF9W.bin toc = none
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroLocalTrack no remote URIs
BraseroLocalTrack stopping
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage stopping
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroChecksumImage output set (IMAGE) image = /tmp/brasero_tmp_ZJFG9W.bin toc = none
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_input_type
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage Starting checksuming file /home/ravbholua/Documents/Other/special/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso (size = 938475520)
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_fd_out
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage Setting new checksum (type = 2) d0508f909c2c71d96aeac5efb0329b33 ((null) before)
BraseroChecksumImage Finished track successfully
BraseroChecksumImage stopping
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibburn unsupported operation
BraseroLibburn deactivating
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_device
BraseroLibburn Drive (/dev/sr0) init result = 1
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_media
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_tracks
BraseroLibburn Setting burnproof 0
BraseroLibburn Setting dummy 0
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn burn_drive_convert_fs_adr( /dev/sr0 )
BraseroLibburn Blanking/Formatting
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_dangerous
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn burn_drive_is_enumerable_adr( /dev/sr0 ) is true
BraseroLibburn Async START UNIT succeeded after 0.1 seconds
BraseroLibburn mmc_set_streaming: end_lba=2295103 ,  r=5540 ,  w=5540
BraseroLibburn Allocating buffer via mmap()
BraseroLibburn Format type 26h "DVD+RW (fs=0,rs=0)", blocks = 4294967295
BraseroLibburn CDB: 04 11 00 00 00 00 
BraseroLibburn Format list: 00 02 00 08 FF FF FF FF 98 00 00 00 

BraseroLibburn syncing cache
BraseroLibburn Async SYNCHRONIZE CACHE succeeded after 0.1 seconds
BraseroLibburn Writing
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_dangerous
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn dvd/bd Profile= 1Ah , obs= 32768 , obs_pad= 0
BraseroLibburn Something went wrong
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_error
BraseroLibburn finished with an error
BraseroLibburn asked to stop because of an error
    error       = 15
    message = "An error occurred while writing to disc"
BraseroLibburn stopping
Session error : An error occurred while writing to disc (brasero_burn_record brasero-burn.c:2856)
```

Then I tried burning the DVD with a video file but now also it failed. What's the issue please? Why I'm failing to do!!!

Comment: @goldilocks O.K. I wasn't aware of that. I have deleted my comment where I addressed to an individual.

Comment: Thanks.  Things would get a little out of hand otherwise, I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it will. Pioneer, [manufacturer](http://www.pioneerelectronics.com/PUSA/Computer/Computer+Drives/DVR-KD08) of your drive states:

> The DVR-KD08 Internal Slim-line DVD/CD Writer from Pioneer offers many
>   industry leading technologies, including:
>
> - **Write Speed**: Up to **8x** on DVD-R/+R, **DVD+RW**, up to 6x on DVD-R DL/+R    DL, DVD-RW, up to 5x on DVD-RAM, up to 24x on CD-R, and
>     up to 24x on    CD-RW
> - Read Speed: Up to 8x on DVD-ROM (SL), DVD-R/+R, DVD-RW/+RW, DVD-ROM    (DL), DVD-R/+R (DL), up to 5x on DVD-RAM, and up to 24x on CD-ROM &
>     CD-R/RW
> - Liquid Crystal Compensator: plays and records to discs more reliably
> - Pioneer technology that compensates for warped discs
> - Meets RoHS and WEEE Directive specifications

The rest is about the quality of the discs and the process i.e. software. Quality plays a huge part in my experience and continually rewriting sessions or data on the same disc introduces an risk of failure which grows with every use. One day, you can try to look for tools to test for c1 and [c2 errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2_error) and visualize [jitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jitter) on your RW compilations. That might also be the day you forget about RW technology - I know I did.

A solution where maybe you can slowly build up and iso file from data ([mkisofs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man8/mkisofs.8.html)/[genisoimage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/genisoimage.1.html) with multiple paths, something), then [md5sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) it each time you use it to confirm integrity, then ultimately write it in one shot - is something I'd look into.

Comment: Thanks for giving me a very good picture on what may happen in future & a way to move ahead. It will help me a lot.

Comment: genisoimage is functionally the current version of the mkisofs tool... Also like the other answer explains, don't miss on [wodim](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/en/man1/wodim.1.html) - both from the cdrkit maintainers. Good luck!

Comment: illuminE & @ultrasawblade oh! it failed to burn. I'm stuck with this issue since 3 days; not able to come out of it.

Comment: All your DVD questions could have been grouped together. Have you ever successfully used that DVD writer at all? Go to the place you got the iso and check if the md5 checksum is valid. Then install the `k3b` software and all dependencies, use that iso as source, don't change the default options except don't write at max speed - use 2x maybe. I suggest a high level solution because you don't seem to provide proper options to the commands you use. You were provided with the growisofs solution, maybe `growisofs -dvd-compat -speed=1 -use-the-force-luke=bufsize:32m -Z /dev/dvdrw=/path/to/dvd.iso` .

Comment: Yes I had used the writer many times to burn CDs & DVDs recently & it worked superbly. I had burned for Windows 7 repair disc (in CD), gparted (in CD), Ubuntu 12.10 (in DVD). But recently since a month I'm seeing that newly purchased blank SONY DVDs & moser baer DVD weren't working. I suspected they are duplicate. For your confirmation I would like to add that these time when they aren't working, Amkette DVD worked. Just now before sending this comment,to test I successfully burned Windows repair iso on Amkette CD-RW. The problem is Amkette DVD isn't available for Ubuntu13.10, CD can't do that

Answer (score 2):

The main thing to look out for is the difference between DVD "plus" RW and DVD "minus" RW.  If the drive only supports one, you can only use that type of blank disc.

However, this model appears to support both DVD "plus" RWs and DVD "minus" RWs (this is based on information retrieved from a couple searches) so your disc should work in this drive.

As far as Linux support for DVD drives, generally any drive (laptop or desktop) with an IDE or SATA interface ought to work great with Linux.  The only optical drives that might present a problem would be ancient ones that connected to a desktop ISA soundcard, or possibly some really old SCSI ones, but both of these pre-date DVD.

I've never used the "Lightscribe" drives that can etch an image on the non-data side of a disc but there appears to be software available [here](http://www.lightscribe.com/downloadsection/linux/index.aspx?id=1372), if your drive can do that.

Applications to write data to discs include `wodim` (command line) and Brasero (graphical).